# What HTTP header indicates when Index.html has been served?

Tags: http-headers

Excuse the awkward title: I'm building a simple web server (don't ask...) and have this problem:

The browser requests `mydomain.com/MyFolder`

My server spots this is a folder, so instead, delivers `mydomain.com/MyFolder/index.html`

All fine so far, except that index.html has link to `mycss.css`, but the browser requests it as a top-level file `mydomain.com/mycss.css` instead of `mydomain.com/myFolder/mycss.css`.

Is there some HTTP header that needs setting up to indicate that a different page has been served? I've tried returning `Content-Location: /myFolder/index.html`, but without any visible success.

`index.html` basically contains this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css" />
```

Comment: I'm afraid, http headers are of no use here, but `base` tag may help you.

Comment: @kirilloid - So you're saying this is an HTML issue rather than a server problem? Does every server suffer from this?

Comment: Have you tried returning `301 Moved Permanently` status instead of the 200 ok? Then you send in the `Location` header and add the slash to the end of the url. Like: `Location: mydomain.com/MyFolder/` and do not serve the index.html just yet, the brower will request again with the slash at the end of the url, only then you serve de html file

Comment: @Delta, Perfect, thanks. Make that an answer, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a `301 Moved Permanently` status code, instead of the `200`.
Provide a Location header pointing to the same url plus a slash in the end /

Like so:

```
Location: mydomain.com/MyFolder/
```

Do not serve the `index.html` file on that same request, wait for the browser to request again with the slash at the end.

Comment: This is the correct approach. Using any HTTP traffic lookup tool, it can be seen that this is what happens with current web servers. Though, you'll need to include the full url, so it would be like `Location: http://mydomain.com/MyFolder/`

Comment: Thanks - while implementing this (and obviously, having bugs in my code) I came across a problem due to 301 caching, so have switched to 302 for now... Here's more: http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/

Answer (score -1):

Can you just try to change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css" />
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/myFolder/mycss.css" />
```

?

Comment: Then try to add a leading slash to your path: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/myFolder/mycss.css" />`

Comment: Absolute paths means stuff is difficult to move. I then can't rename folders without editing their content.

Comment: The answer is - create your `.htaccess` file and that's it.

Answer (score -1):

Or just try to add something like this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule   ^(.+)$ myFolder/$1
```

Comment: I don't have an .htaccess file ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, actually the information given was not correct so I'm modifying the answer. If you are implementing a web-server, you must follow the standard specification. The definition `<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css" />` shall retrieve the the CSS file from the same location as the file in which it is defined in (`index.html`) is. When using relative paths, it is not the browser that requests from a specific location but the web-server should determine the location from which to serve the resource.

Check section 2.4.6 and 3 in the standards document: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt

In other words, if the path of a resource does not start with the slash (/), it is considered as relative and should be located relative to the base URL.

Comment: So is `./mycss.css` different from `mycss.css`?